# A calculation in Ricci soliton

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the paper

*Cao, Huai-Dong*, [**Geometry of Ricci solitons**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11401-005-0379-2), Chin. Ann. Math., Ser. B 27, No. 2, 121-142 (2006). [ZBL1102.53025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1102.53025), there is a statement saying that; if $g_{ij}$ is a complete gradient Ricci soliton on the Riemannian manifold $M$, i.e.,
$$R_{ij}+\nabla_i\nabla_jf=\lambda g_{ij},$$ then we obtain
$$\nabla_iR_{jk}-\nabla_jR_{ik}+R_{ijkl}\nabla_lf=0.$$ I can not get how this result comes. Please help me to find the intermediate calculation.

Comment: Differentiate the soliton equation to get a formula for $\nabla_iR_{jk},$ use this to expand $\nabla_iR_{jk} - \nabla_j R_{ik}$ and then apply the definition of the curvature to rewrite the third derivatives of $f$.

Comment: This is essentially Ricci identity